# How were the light cycles supposed to going to stop the light runner from escaping?

Tags: tron-legacy

In Tron Legacy, when Quora saves Sam, 3 light cycles are released to stop them from escaping in the light runner. Later is mentioned the light runner is the fastest vehicle on the grid. The light cycles didnt fire any arm, so I'm assuming they dont have any, unlike the light runner which threw mines at them and had other arms, supposedly they couldnt overspeed it to create a wall of light they would crash into, because "it was the fastest vehicle on the grid", and certainly they can't push it for it to crash, unlike the light runner which can and did push one of the light cycles to crash. And I doubt they could harm it with the identity discs due to its size, or could they?

How were the light cycles supposed to going to stop the light runner from escaping?

Comment: _Quora_ knows it's the fastest vehicle; do we have any reason to expect that Clu and his minions know that?  It seems to be the kind of thing that Quora and Flynn wouldn't brag about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light-cycles have a single weapon and a single method of deploying it, the wake caused by their progress through the grid level.

Even though the light-runner is faster and better armed than the cycles (note that this is something that Clu doesn't know at this point), the fact that they have a 3:1 advantage should be sufficient to allow them to box in the light-runner, resulting in it either crashing or stopping and allowing the arrest of the driver and passenger. Clu is basically fine with either outcome, thinking that Flynn is the driver.